# Programming Logic: How to Check for Neighbors in a Grid?

Tags: java, grid

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to think of a logical way to check for neighbors in a "grid"-based programming project for class.

The main problem I'm having is thinking of a way to effectively check whether its on the sides so that I don't get an index out of bounds error.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that I'm using a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: What data structure you are using?

Comment: oh yea my bad, a 2-dimensional array

Comment: A technique used in many algorithms is to make the array 1 larger in width and height, and therefore avoid index out of bounds and a lot of if-sentences. Of cause, the value in the first row and column needs to not effect the validity of the algorithm so whether you can use it is depending on the specific case.

Comment: FWIW @lasseespeholt, I think your comment is a far better answer than any of the answers.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple way of getting a neighbour position avoiding worrying about the sides:

```
int leftX = (x - 1 + width) % width;
int rightX = (x + 1) % width;
int aboveY = (y - 1 + height) % height;
int belowY = (y + 1) % height;
```

It's possibly not the most efficient way of doing it, but it keeps each calculation to a single, simple expression. That's assuming you want wrap-around, of course. If you don't, you'll *have* to do things conditionally:

```
if (x > 0)
{
    // Use x - 1
}
if (x < width - 1)
{
    // Use x + 1
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Basically you want to access the neighbor of a cell, while ensuring you are not out of the grid. You can try a simple algorithm:

Provided that the center cell (where *you* are) is `(x,y)`, and that you want to check the diagonals as well.
Your grid is [0,W[ on X, and [0,H[ on Y (basically `W x H`, starting from (0,0))

```
  for (i=-1 ; i<2 ; i++)    
    for (j=-1 ; j<2 ; j++)
      if (i !=0 && j != 0)
  {
     rx = x + i;
     ry = y + j;

     if (rx >= 0 && ry >= 0 && rx < W && ry < H)
     {
       // I'm in
     }
     else
     {
       // I'm out
     }

  }
```

This can be optimized on (i,j), e.g. `i` starts from 0 if `x` is 0.

If you don't want the diagonals, you only have to check `(x-1,y)` `(x+1,y)` `(x,y-1)` and `(x,y+1)`,

```
  for (i=-1 ; i<2 ; i+=2)
  {
     // check (x+i, y)
     // check (x, y+i)
  }
```

Comment: Avoid comment like thanks or +1... +1 ++ Thanks! By the way, suppose you want grid neighbors without diagonals from a specific known location:
`for( int i = -1; i < 2; ++i )
 {

     int dX = x + i, dY = y + i;

    // Horizontals:
    grid[dX][y];

   // Verticals:
   if( i != 0 )
       grid[x][dY]

`

Answer (score 4):

What's it a 2d array of? Perhaps some objects that have state such as "Occupied" and "Empty" or some such? In which case introdcuce a new state such as "Edge" and "Corner" and create the 2-D array 1 cell bigger in every direction. Then your neighbour checker can just use simple +/- logic and then the processing for the set of neighbours can choose to ignore any edges.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, the left neighbour of [x,y] is [x,y-1] and the right neighbour is [x,y+1], and so on. However, you should also check that y>=1, otherwise you will go out of bounds. Similarly, y must be less than the size of the array. You can do that with an if statement or alternatively (not recommended) you can handle the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 1):

There's often (if not always) a sacrifice in term of speed vs. memory; I had to implement a Sudoku solver some time ago in Java, and it was faster to assign each cell a list of cell groups. So, instead of checking boundaries every time, I simply had to iterate over each group, then each cell within each groups. The check was made once to create the groups.

Something like :

```
class Neighbors {
   ArrayList<Point> pList = new ArrayList<Point>();
}
```

...

```
int[][] grid = new int[10][10];
Neighbors[][] n = new Neighbors[10][10];

for (int x=0; x<10; x++) {
   for (int y=0; y<10; y++) {
      grid[x][y] = (y*10)+x;  // 0..99
      n[x][y] = new Neighbors();
      for (int nx=x-1; nx<=x+1; nx++) {
         for (int ny=y-1; ny<=y+1; ny++) {
            if (!(x==nx && y==ny) && nx>=0 && ny>=0 && nx<10 && ny<10) {
               n[x][y].pList.add(new Point(nx,ny)); // add valid neighbor
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

then, for any given point : x, y

```
for (Point p : n[x][y].pList) {
   // grid[p.x][p.y]  is a neighbor of grid[x][y]
}
```

Well, my solution was a little more sophisticated, but the principle is the same. If your grid is a 2-dimension array of objects, the neighbors can actually be the object at `grid[nx][ny]` instead of points for direct object access.

You will eventually need to check for `x>=0`, `y>=0`, `x<SIZE_W`, and `y<SIZE_H`, but this solution does the check only onece, so it is in my opinion quite efficient when querying neighbors often for each grid cell. If you need to resize the grid often, then this solution would need to be adapted.

Another approach would be to pad your array in each direction with `ignored` flag value (such as null, -1, etc.) and simply do a normal check ignoring such cells :

```
int pad_size = 1;  // how many neighbors around x,y
int size_w = 10+(pad_size*2);
int size_h = 10+(pad_size*2);
int[][] grid = new int[size_w][size_h];

for (int x=0; x<size_w; x++) {
  for (int y=0; y<size_h; y++) {
     if (x<pad_size || x>=size_w-pad_size || y<pad_size || y>=size_h-pad_size) {
        grid[x][y] = -1;  // ignore
     } else {
        grid[x][y] = ((y-pad_size)*10)+(x-pad-size);  // 0..99
     }
  }
}
```

then for any given point : x,y

```
for (int nx=x-pad_size; nx<=x+pad_size; nx++) {
  for (int ny=y-pad_size; ny<=y+pad_size; ny++) {
     if (-1!=grid[nx][ny] && !(nx==x && ny==y)) {
        // grid[p.x][p.y]  is a neighbor of grid[x][y]
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about factoring out the bits you need?  Something like an `isOccupied(x,y)` method that returns false for out-of-bounds values:

```
  public boolean isOccupied(int x, int y) {
    if (!inXRange(x) || !inYRange(y))
      return false;
    return occupied[y][x]; // or [x][y] depending on row/col major preferences
  }
```

Then the count neighbours method will be pretty straightforward:

```
  public int countNeighbours(int x, int y) {
    int neighbours = 0;
    for (int dx = -1; dx <= 1; ++dx) {
      for (int dy = -1; dy <= 1; ++dy) {
        if (((dx != 0) || (dy != 0)) && isOccupied(x + dx, y + dy))
          neighbours += 1;
      }
    }
    return neighbours;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Way too late, but the answers provided is either too complicate or incomplete ihmo so I will try to answer it.

Basically what u want to do is find the deviation from `x` and `y` ranging from -1 to 1. so maximum number of neighbors is 3^2 - 1 (the node itself).

Now if your grid has boundaries, just check if the new `x` and `y` are still within boundaries.

```js
const x = 6;
const y = 1;

const W = 7;
const H = 7;

const neighbors = [];

for (a = -1; a < 2; a++) {
    for (b = -1; b < 2; b++) {
        if (!(a == 0 && b == 0)) {
            const nX = x + a;
            const nY = y + b;
            if ((nX >= 0 && nX < W) && (nY >= 0 && nY < H)) {
                neighbors.push(`${nX}, ${nY}`);
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(neighbors);
```